# Deploying software that depends on a virtual machine using Docker

Tags: docker, virtualbox

## About

I am developing a piece of software which consists of a Node.js application which controls a virtual machine that runs Android-x86. Also there are some pieces of the Android SDK like ADB the software depends on.

## My current approach

Currently there is no smart way of deployment whatsoever at all. Everything has to be installed manually. Depending on the system I also get issues regarding networking and so on from time to time.

To solve problems of these kinds I usually would use Docker. Therefore that was my first thought here as well. So such a Docker container would simply run the Node.js application as well as the virtual machine.

## My problem

For me it became a bit confusing (and maybe even pointless) when I wanted to use a virtual machine inside of a Docker container. Due to there is obviously no way I can run an Android-x86 Docker container I cannot come up with any other solution than a virtual machine inside of Docker.

## My question

Is it fine to do as I mentioned or are there any better ways or even best practices to use a virtual machine inside of a container?

## Edits

- I want to add that a possible solution does not have to be utilizing Docker. If there is any other technology that is able to create a container-ish construct which in further consequence is able to run a virtual machine I would be happy to get to know it.

Answer (score 2):

Frankly, I've never seen running a VM inside Docker. I believe it would be very slow. Have you checked if https://github.com/budtmo/docker-android is useful?

This Video talks about the Docker and Android SDK as well - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YwBAqMDYFCU

Comment: Thanks for the contribution! Speed is not too much of a problem for my purpose to be honest. I checked out projects like the one you linked, yes. They all use the Android Emulator instead of the Android-x86 project. I probably can make it work with an Android emulator as well but I prefer the Android-x86 approach.